# Proving that the center of a factor group is trivial

Tags: group-theory

Prove that the center of the factor group $G/Z(G)$ is the trivial subgroup $[e]$.

So far I've proved that $Z(G)$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ for all $a \in G $.

Comment: Show what you have done already.

Comment: $Z(G/Z(G))$ needn't be trivial. Indeed, one can continue taking centers of quotients and pulling back farther in general; it's called the ascending central series.

Comment: If Z(G) is a normal of G, then for $c\in G, c^{-1}Z(G)c \subset Z(G)$. Z(G) is defined as { $a\in G$ | ax = xa for all $x\in G$}, therefore for all $a\in Z(G)$ satisfies $c^{-1}ac \subset Z(G)$ and therefore $c^{-1}Z(G)c \subset Z(G)$. By definition of the normal group, Z(G) is a normal subgroup of G.

Comment: ^But in that case, $G=G/Z(G)$ is centerless.

Comment: The last sentence isn't worded quite right.  You may have proved that $Z(G)$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.  In doing so, you have proved that $aZ(G)a^{-1}=Z(G)$ for all $a\in G$.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/q/780802/

Comment: @blue (Just to add: This is also known as the *upper* central series. Such a series is non-trivial for non-abelian *[nilpotent groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nilpotent_group)*, for example $p$-groups. So a counter-example would be any non-abelian $p$-group.)

Answer (score 3):

I suspect yours is an incomplete quote of [Grün's Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_group#Gr.C3.BCn.27s_lemma):

> If $G$ is a *perfect* group, then $Z(G/Z(G)) = \{ 1 \}$.

Here $G$ is a perfect group if $G = G'$.

The Wikipedia link above gives the short proof, which is based on the [Three Subgroups Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_subgroups_lemma) - in every group one has that the second center commutes with the derived subgroup. (There's a more general statements about appropriate terms of the upper and lower central series commuting.)

Answer (score 2):

This is false: $Q_8/\langle -1\rangle\cong V_4$, which is abelian and thus has a nontrivial center.

Answer (score 0):

is it true that $Z(G/Z(G)) \ne \{1\}$ iff $\exists a \in G - Z(G)$. such that the generated group $ \langle Z(G),a \rangle $ is a normal subgroup (not necessarily proper) of $G$?