# Find a group G such that Z(G/Z(G)) is nontrivial when Z(G) is the center of G.

Tags: group-theory

So far I've tried using the quaternion group :

$G = \{-1, 1, i, -i, j, -j, k, -k\}$ and $Z(G) = \{-1, 1\}$.

I'm kind of stuck from here?

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: I take it you're [this user](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/882224/proving-that-the-center-of-a-factor-group-is-trivial#comment1820605_882224), and that you're having trouble figuring out how $Q_8/Z(Q_8)\cong V_4$?

Answer (score 3):

You are basically finished.  If we let $G = \mathcal{Q}$, then $Z(G) = \{-1, 1\}$.  Since $|G| = 8$, then the factor group $G/Z(G)$ has order $4$, and is therefore isomorphic to either $\mathbb{Z}_4$ or $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$.

Blue is correct in his answer that it is actually isomorphic to the Klein four-group ($\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$).  However, it isn't necessary to actually prove this.  Instead, recognize that both possible groups are abelian, and the center of an abelian group is the entire group.  In particular, the center must be nontrivial.

Comment: One would still need to prove a group of order four must be abelian to use the fact (and the OP doesn't seem to be at the level where they can just assume that).

Comment: @blue I'm with you in thinking the op doesn't know that, but talking about centers and quotients is prime territory for proving groups of order $p^2$ are abelian, since it follows from the $G/Z(G)$ cyclic implication, so they're at a level in their class where they *could* do it, in theory.

Comment: @Adam Yes! ${}$

Comment: Alternatively, he could observe that every element of the quotient group has order $1$ or $2$, which forces the group to be abelian.

Comment: @blue, I certainly sympathize with what you are saying.  The classification of groups of order $4$ was one of the first things I learned in my course on group theory, so I suppose it depends on where the OP is in his material.  It's possible to show the result with nothing more than the group axioms, Lagrange's theorem, and taking cases when constructing a multiplication table.

Comment: Alternately, one can apply the fact that the center of a $p$-group is nontrivial.

Answer (score 2):

The quotient of the quaternion group by its center is the Klein four group, $V_4=C_2\times C_2$.

Reason as follows: the quotient $Q_8/Z(Q_8)$ has order four, whose elements are $[1],[i],[j],[k]$, and we easily check that all three nontrivial elements have order two and commute. There is only one group with that property, namely $C_2\times C_2$. (By the way, can you prove that?)

Since $V_4$ is abelian, its center is $Z(V_4)=V_4\ne1$.