# Nonabelian finite $G$ such that $O(g) \subseteq Z(G)g, \forall g \in G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions

Is there any nonabelian finite group $G$ such that:

$$O(g) \subseteq Z(G)g, \forall g \in G \tag 1$$

where $O(g)$ is the orbit "by $g$" of the natural action of $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ on $G$, namely $\sigma \cdot g := \sigma(g)$?

Comment: In initial thoughts: Whenever you have a group satisfying $O(g)\subseteq Z(G)g$, then, by considering conjugation automorphisms, we get that the commutator subgroup is a subgroup of the centre. Feels to me like that should tell us something but I can't figure out what.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou, related to this, if helps, I think to have proven that such groups (if any) have $\operatorname{Inn}(G) \le Z(\operatorname{Aut}(G))$.

Comment: So you are looking for nilpotent groups of class 2 in which all automorphisms are central. I am sure there are such examples -  I will investigate further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three (isomorphism classes of) groups of order 64 with this property, which are $\mathtt{SmallGroup}(64,i)$ with $i=68,69,116$ in the small groups database.

They all have commutator subgroup $[G,G] \cong C_2 \times C_2$ with $G/[G,G] \cong C_2 \times C_2 \times C_4$. The first two have $Z(G) \cong C_2^3$ and automorphism groups of order $512$, and the third has $Z(G) \cong C_2 \times C_4$ and automorphism group of order $128$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Now that three (up to isomorphism) real cases are at hand, I'd like to confirm that they all fulfil the property $\operatorname{Inn}(G) \le Z(\operatorname{Aut}(G))$, as this latter has brought me to pose the question. Is it really so?

Comment: Yes - in fact ${\rm Aut}(G)$ is abelian in all three cases.